# Virtual Host on CentOS5

Tags: apache, centos

I'm trying to add a new virtual host to a CentOS 5 box.

I've added a new section in virtualhost.conf matching existing entries:

```
<VirtualHost ip address:80>
    ServerAdmin email@email.com
    DocumentRoot /home/stuff/public_html
    ServerName stuff.stuff.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/stuff.stuff.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/stuff.stuff.com-access_log combined
    <Directory /home/stuff/public_html>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
      AssignUserId stuff stuff
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I then do a reload using the command: `/etc/init.d/httpd reload`

I've put a placeholder index.php in the directory, and would expect to see an "it works" when visiting the domain, but instead Chrome shows "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

What steps am I missing here? (I'm used to working in a windows environment, this is my first real encounter with CentOS)

Comment: Chrome failing to resolve the DNS name to its IP address, is probably not related to the Apache config. Is the name `stuff.stuff.com` registered in DNS ? Does it resolve if you `ping stuff.stuff.com` from the client machine you're trying to access it from?

Comment: Nope, doesn't return anything when I ping it. This looks like it could be DNS rather than config.

Comment: If you are working on localhost than try editing you /etc/hosts file. Change your hostname and point it to your IP address in /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this as a DNS issue, resolved locally editing hosts to match the IP.