# Virtual host on httpd redirect unintentionally

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

### My goal

Running 2 name virtual host with 1 IP. For example, `front1.httpd.example.com` and `front2.httpd.example.com` are accesible on 1 server's 1 httpd (parent) process(I want to listen on port 80 in both front1 and front2).

### Environment

httpd 2.4 and Ubuntu 11(32bit)

### What I did

I added to two virtual host on httpd.conf according to the latest offical document [Name-based Virtual Host Support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/vhosts/name-based.html).

And also I update my server /etc/hosts and client hosts like the following.

server's hosts(220.xxx.xxx.xxx is some actual IP)

```
127.0.0.1 front1.httpd.example.com front2.httpd.example.com localhost

220.xxx.xxx.xxx front1.httpd.example.com
222.xxx.xxx.xxx front2.httpd.example.com
```

client's hosts

```
220.xxx.xxx.xxx front1.httpd.example.com
220.xxx.xxx.xxx front2.httpd.example.com
```

In addition, my hostname is `front1.httpd.example.com`

(Note: I also tried to add `NameVirtualHost *:80` before the VirtualHost sections, but it just returns additional message "NameVirtualHost has no effect...")

### Results

When I access to `front1.httpd.example.com/index.html`, `htdocs/xxxx/index.html` is returned. This is what I expected, but when I access to `front2.httpd.example.com/index.html`, also `htdocs/xxxx/index.html` is returned in spite of I intend to show `htdocs/yyyy/index.html`.
(in browser console message, `front2.httpd.example.com/index.html` is found and then 302 redirect to `front1.httpd.example.com/index.html`)

Virtual host will return the first Virtual host value if there is no matching result to access. So, I also tried to change the oreder of the virtual host like the following:

First try:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/xxxx"
    ServerName front1.httpd.example.com
    ServerAlias front1.httpd.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host1.example.com-error_log"

    <Directory "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/xxxx">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/yyyy"
    ServerName front2.httpd.example.com
    ServerAlias front2.httpd.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    <Directory "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/yyyy">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and second try:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/yyyy"
    ServerName front2.httpd.example.com
    ServerAlias front2.httpd.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    <Directory "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/yyyy">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/xxxx"
    ServerName front1.httpd.example.com
    ServerAlias front1.httpd.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host1.example.com-error_log"

    <Directory "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/xxxx">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As a result, `front2.httpd.example.com/index.html` returns `htdocs/yyyy/index.html`, but `front1.httpd.example.com/index.html` also returns `htdocs/yyyy/index.html`. Therefore, I guess accessing request does not much any virtual host.

### Refs and comments

I checked similar questions like this [Virtual Host on CentOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120041/virtual-host-on-centos5), but in my case I wrote hosts file on the both server and client, so DNS things are not for me, I think.

I had setup the httpd server for past a few years and also used `VirtualHost` with old stuff `NameVirtualHost`, but this time something I screwed up or I don't know.
Please provide me any ideas?

### My httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "/opt/APACHE/httpd"

Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/xxxx"
    ServerName front1.httpd.example.com
    ServerAlias front1.httpd.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host1.example.com-error_log"

    <Directory "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/xxxx">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/yyyy"
    ServerName front2.httpd.example.com
    ServerAlias front2.httpd.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    <Directory "/opt/APACHE/httpd/htdocs/yyyy">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User ubuntu
Group ubuntu
</IfModule>

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/APACHE/httpd/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/opt/APACHE/httpd/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using OpenAM Web policy agent at this server instance.

As a result, just adding each FQDN to the FQDN virtual mapping on OpenAm agent profile reach the my goal.